# Can I use PipedStreams to send Data from one Thread to multiple others?

Tags: java, multithreading, inputstream, outputstream

I am programming a multi-threaded server and I have a thread for every client-socket-connection.
I want to pass data from the main thread back and forth to the client-threads.

How many threads do I have to set up?

Does it work like this:

[Server Class:]

```
private PipedInputStream serverInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
private PipedOutputStream serverOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();
public PipedInputStream clientInputStream = new PipedInputStream();
public PipedOutputStream clientOutputStream = new PipedOutputStream();

serverInputStream.connect(clientOutputStream);
clientInputStream.connect(serverOutputStream);
```

or do I have to set up a these four of Streams for each client?

I apologize if this question is maybe dumb, but I have seen that as a possebility and tried it.
If there is a much better way to handle communication between threads then please educate me!

I have written a small Class that waits for a Buffered Reader that blocks and add the messages to the queue:

```
public class DataListener implements Runnable {

    private InputStream is;
    private ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> messages;
    private boolean closed = false;

    public DataListener(InputStream is, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<String> messages) {
        this.is = is;
        this.messages = messages;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while (!closed) {
            try {
                messages.add(br.readLine());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        closed = true;
    }
}
```

Can you tell me if that is a good way of working around a blocking listener?

Comment: I think you could use my [`OutputStreamMultiplier`](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/need-to-write-same-content-to-multiple.html) to send the output to all of them for you.

Comment: You shouldn't need to use streams to communicate between threads in your application.  If you need separate queues for each client thread, consider using `BlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is definitely not a good idea to use streams to pass data from one thread to another, because:

- Stream IO are blocking operations, which would put the thread on hold.
- Streams (in general) are not thread-safe by default, which could lead to all kinds of issues.

If you want to pass data between threads frequently try to avoid blocking at all cost, because otherwise the server thread will be waiting most of the time. Java offers a wide tool-set of non-blocking data exchange functionality that you can use instead, which you can find in the [Concurrent Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

A very simple yet effective and fast way to exchange data is to use a message-style system:

```
final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyMessageClass> messages = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<MyMessageClass>();

public void addMessage(final MyMessageClass message) {
  messaged.add(message);
}

protected void serverLoop() {
  //...
  final MyMessageClass message = messages.poll(); // does not block, returns null if none is available
  if (message != null) {
    handleMessage(message);
  }
  //...
}
```

You can use other classes like the `LinkedBlockingQueue` for additional features like temporary blocking.

**However:** when it comes to threading most problems can only be solved by using the correct architecture for your problem at hand. There is no "golden hammer" solution for all your threading tasks, if you want your code to run flawlessly, you need to find the appropriate solution.

Comment: I agree with most of your answer, but obviously piped streams are thread-safe, that being what they're designed for. Useless, but thread-safe.

Comment: I am definitly going to try that, too!
It looks really good for my thread-setup.

Comment: Why exactly are the finals there?

Comment: (Edited the question)
Can you tell me if you see something that I could imidiately improve in my new code or if something is probably going to break, which I did not think of?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use any given piped steam pair between two threads. You will need a pair of pioed streams per thread pair. Don't do this. Use a queue.